# UIImage as method return value

Tags: ios, xcode

Having my first dab at Xcode (5.1.1) today.

I am trying to associate an image with a UIImageView component inside a table view cell. Direct reference to the image works, but via method call fails:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonCell" ];

    Person *person = (self.persons)[indexPath.row];

    UILabel *labelName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:50];
    labelName.text = person.name;

    UIImageView *imageViewPic = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:51];

    // WORKS OK
    //imageViewPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticks"];

    // FAILS (no image in cell)
    //[imageViewPic setImage:[self imageForScore:person.score]];
    imageViewPic.image = [self imageForScore:person.score];

    return cell;
}

-(UIImage *)imageForScore:(int)score
{
    switch (score) {
        case 1: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"];
        case 2: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I've confirmed that a valid score of 1 or 2 is passed in, but image in cell is always blank (via method call).

What am I missing?

Comment: How exactly have you confirmed that the value of score is 1 or 2. Use a breakpoint. What is the value of score in the failing case?

Comment: check the value of person.score

Comment: Use of breakpoint confirms hitting individual cases. Just no image shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you've confirmed that `score` is truly `1` or `2` when this method is called, there are two logical sources of the problem:

1. The call to `imageNamed` is failing. There are a couple of possible reasons why it could fail:

   - Are the `tick` and `cross` images included in your bundle (under "Copy Bundle Resoures")?

     [image: bundle contents]

     Or if using `Images.xcassets`, are the images there?

     Either way, confirm the capitalization of the image name.
   - You're not providing an extension. If loading it from bundle resources (but not `Images.xcassets`), you have to specify the extension if the file is not a PNG file (e.g. if it is a JPEG file). Try specifying the extension if not using `Images.xcassets`.
2. If, on the other hand, you confirm that `imageForScore` is returning a valid `UIImage`, you might want to confirm that `imageViewPic` is correct.

   - It's possible that `imageViewPic`, itself, is `nil` (perhaps a subview with the tag of `51` was not found).
   - I might also suggest confirming the other properties of the `imageViewPic` (e.g. the `frame` is valid, that the `hidden` flag is not turned on, etc.).

Comment: Good advice in general but nothing here answers the question, which is essentially "what is wrong with my `-(UIImage *)imageForScore:(int)score` method?"

Comment: He might be using image.xcassets so that no extension needed. And though he said that it worked fine when he directly associate the imageview.

Comment: Good points by both of you. I've attempted to clarify my answer accordingly.

Comment: My images are indeed within MiscImages.xcassets and visible. Direct use of imageViewPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"]; works fine (see comment in code), just the call via method fails to show image.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore -- fault found! Mismatch on file names (ticks.png and cros.png) !